# Remove Commas with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am in need of some code that removes commas from a string.
I currently have a variety of numbers in the number_format() for PHP.
I use Jquery to post certain things to a update page and I need the commas removed from a class.

for instance here is some code.

```
<span class="money">1,234,567</span>
```

I want the value of the code I post to be 1234567 instead of 1,234,567.
I would like to use Jquery if that's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var noCommas = $('.money').text().replace(/,/g, ''),
    asANumber = +noCommas;
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe. This one worked for me and replaced all commas. I also like that you included how to convert to a number.

Comment: @stephen-hanson is this what you want????  var asANumber  = parseFloat($('.money').text().replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 6):

This is a clean way to get rid of the commas in one line, without loops.

```
    var cleanNumber = $("#selector").val().split(",").join("");
```

Hope can help u!

Answer (score 4):

Less is more! (sometimes!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var **stripString** = $('.money').text().replace(/,/g, '');
$('.*money*').text(**stripString**);
});
```

Comment: This is the only one that removed all the commas, all others just removed the first comma for some reason.

Comment: Joe's response removes all commas.

Comment: Mine gave actual context. Something vets often neglect because they think that it's obvious and everyone should know. Also, you should never convert it to a number like he did... (var a = +b) that's terrible coding practices. The correct way (like everything in my example, would be to use parseInt(number, radix).

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
var str=$(".money").text();
var str2=   str.replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with this , will remove comma on click on textbox , after focusout thousand seperated will be added...

```js
$( "#salary" ).click(function() {

   $( "#salary" ).val(  $("#salary").val().replace(/,/g, ''));

});



$( "#salary" ).blur(function() {

   $( "#salary" ).val( addCommas($( "#salary" ).val());

});

function addCommas(nStr) {

    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use replace function of javascript for removing , in a string

```
var result = jQuery('.money').html().replace(',', '');
alert(result);
```