# Jquery removing commas

Tags: php, jquery, replace

I'm using the following and it works, but the alerted value `opt3` contains commas.

How do I remove them?

```
form method='get' action='form.php'>
    <select name='val' class='select' id='opt1' multiple>
        <option></option>
        <option value='a'>a</option>
        <option value='b'>b</option>
        <option value='c'>c</option>
        <option value='d'>d</option>
    </select>
    <select name='opt' id='opt2'>
        <option value='AAA'>AAA</option>
        <option value='BBB'>BBB</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' onClick="return function1();">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function function1(){
        var opt1=document.getElementById("opt1").value;
        var opt2=document.getElementById("opt2").value;
        var opt3=$('#opt1').val();
        alert( opt3 );
        var response=confirm("Are you sure? option1="+opt1+" option2="+opt2+" option3="+opt3 );
        return response;
     }
```

If I select a c & d the alert shows a,c,d but I want it to show acd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Commas with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802014/remove-commas-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
var opt3=$('#opt1').val().replace(",","");
```

**Update:**

Ok. Like @jreziga mentioned. The return value of `.val()` will be an array. If you have a string the upper code example will do just fine. 
If you have an array like in your case you can do this:

```
var opt3=$('#opt1').val().join("");
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Any way to reverse the output ? so I get `dca` returned ?

Comment: Sorted using var `opt3=$('#opt1').val().reverse().join("");`

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
$('#opt1').val()
```

it returns an array for multiple values.

Instead of .replace, you can try this :

```
$('#opt1').val().join(';')
```

You can change the separator ";", or use a loop like this :

```
var str = $('#opt1').val();
for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
   alert(str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all commas

```
var opt3=$('#opt1').val();
opt3 = opt3.replace(/,/g, "");
alert(opt3);
```

where `,` is the special character so escaped with `/` and `g` is to replace global occurances.

Answer (score 0):

use [replace](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method in jquery for removing all commas from the value

```
var opt3 = $('#opt1').val().replace(/,/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var opt3=$('#opt1').val().replace(/,/g, '');//replace all comma
        alert( opt3 );
```